# Android App: Image Recognition or Augmented Reality to detect Images and do operations

Tags: android, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I have to retrieve data from the database based on the image recognized...

What would be better? Do you have any ideas or what are the ways to do this?
I hope Augmented Reality doesn't need here.

Please suggest some image recognition SDK based on my needs...

Also suggest me how would I link the image and the data in the database???

Thanks in advance

Comment: might be this project help you https://github.com/Catchoom/craftar-example-android-image-recognition

Comment: this one two http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV is famous open source framework for Image Processing and Computer Vision. Here is it's Android SDK. [OpenCV Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)